When I insert 'pip install quant' in VSCODE terminal, there is an error
When I Insert this code,
from quant_infos.wics_code import *

An error occured.
The error name is subprocess-exited-with-error and metadata-generation-failed error.
How can I find a solution for this error?
programming language is python and develop environment is VS Code.

The latest version of quant on PyPI is 0.9 which was released in 2014. It may not be compatible with your Python version

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
